# How do I make a Turkish Delight Syrup

Tags: ice-cream, candy

I made turkish delight ice cream but the bits of commercial sugar coated turkish delight I folded through were rock hard when frozen and a possible problem for unsuspecting guests.  So, I was wanting a solution and thought maybe making a thick sauce or a much softer turkish delight may be the answer and folding that through after churning.  Any advice on how to fix this please.

Answer (score 2):

I would make a stock syrup including some liquid glucose to discourage crystallisation, then flavour it with rose water and give it some colour with red/pink gel food colouring. You should then be able to fold it through to make a Turkish Delight Ripple ice cream.

Comment: I generally don't approve of the "modernist cuisine" methods, but I wonder if in this specific case, some agar agar or xantham gum might be indicated, to help prevent the syrup from freezing to a rock hard texture, as it won't be churned and thus aerated if used as a ripple.  Perhaps some of the experts on that topic could could add their thoughts....

Comment: A good idea. I'm unaware of the properties of those substances when frozen.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ an actual syrup (with high enough sugar content) does not freeze. No need for additives.

Comment: Not quite true; it will just freeze into ice crystals and more sugary syrup.  The ice cream base itself has as its main phase a sugar/water solution, and it freezes.  Either part of the ice cream will freeze until it is in equilibrium between ice crystals and concentrated syrup where it is thermodynamically unfavorable to separate out any more ice.  However, unlike the base ice cream, the syrup phase does not get churned or mechanically agitated to facilitate growth of many small crystals, so it will have larger ice crystals, leading to a crunchy or gritty texture.

Comment: Who asked you, man? ;)