# How can I make a chocolate syrup that can be frozen?

Tags: chocolate, syrup

I am looking to make a chocolate syrup without eggs, that freezes well.

Comment: Hi Dhara and welcome to the site! As far as I know, there are no eggs in most regular chocolate syrups. Have you already tried freezing one? If so, what went wrong or what didn't you like about it?

Comment: A bit more detail about what you are trying to do would be useful. Why do you want to freeze chocolate syrup?

Comment: Take any recipe for chocolate sorbet and freeze it without churning.

Comment: I have not tried anything but i am searching on google but dint find any thing

Comment: Why is freezing an issue?  Chocolate syrup has a fairly long shelf life in the refrigerator to start with, due to the osmotic pressure the high levels of sugar create, and due to some of the natural components of the cocoa such as theobromine which are anti-bacterial in nature.  If you are looking to make a a confection or dessert, as others have said, please describe your goals.  See also this thread (mostly the comments) about freezing a syrup ripple in ice cream:  http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/32016/how-do-i-make-a-turkish-delight-syrup

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ I want to create a solid layer like on the chocobar icecreams

Comment: Do you mean a chocolate coating, like on, for example, Dove bars?  These are generally not syrup based.  See, for example, http://www.chow.com/recipes/29580-chocolate-shell-ice-cream-topping

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ no something like this http://www.google.co.in/imgres?imgurl=http://toi.amul.com/icecream/is-chocobar.jpg&imgrefurl=http://toi.amul.com/icecream/atreats.html&h=339&w=438&sz=43&tbnid=6jUZVX5SCnWGRM:&tbnh=90&tbnw=116&zoom=1&usg=__116xO98JKu4ELm7Hi4aoK9sjbCM=&docid=nL0kTwJc4gVZqM&sa=X&ei=ZqGUUaX1J8n3rQfAl4CYAQ&ved=0CDUQ9QEwAQ&dur=296

Comment: Dove bars are basically the same thing :-)

Comment: @Dhara this is not chocolate syrup, this is chocolate glaze. They are very different from a cooking point of view.

Comment: related: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/16282/no-melt-chocolate-coating-on-ice-cream-bars/16283#16283

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common methods to create chocolate coated ice cream bars, with or without a stick are to:

1. Use truly tempered chocolate, which may be more trouble than it is worth
2. Use a mixture of chocolate thinned with vegetable oil.

See for example, this recipe from [Serious Eats](http://www.seriouseats.com/recipes/2011/06/homemade-chocolate-covered-ice-cream-bars-recipe.html).

Comment: But i want a homemade recipie to made the outer cover only

Comment: So just use that part of the recipe.